# How should I correctly pass a JDBC URL to the ignite3 cli command?

Tags: ignite

I am currently working with the ignite3 cli command and noticed that there's an option -u to specify a JDBC URL to connect to the Ignite cluster:

```
# ignite3
# -u, --jdbc-url=<jdbc>      JDBC url to ignite cluster
./ignite3 sql -u 172.17.0.3:11211 "SELECT * FROM SYS.TABLES"
```

I was wondering if there are any specific examples or best practices on how this JDBC URL should be passed. Does anyone have experience with this or could guide me on the correct format and usage?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JDBC URL for this option should be the same JDBC URL that is used for regular JDBC connections, i.e. it should be prefixed according to JDBC URL structure convention including subprotocol and driver type, so the correct URL should look like:

```
jdbc:ignite:thin://172.17.0.3:11211
```

I would also recommend to double-check the port, since the default port for all thin client connections is 10800.

Best regards!